# Как работает магический метод __add__ в python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Вот код:

```
class Add():
    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument

    def __add__(self, other):
        return other + self.argument
z = Add(12)
x = Add(2)
t = z + x
print(t)
```

Он работает. Причин критиковать возможно и нет.

А вот еще код с одной новой строчкой.

```
class Add():
    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument

    def __add__(self, other):
        print(self.argument + other)
        return other + self.argument

z = Add(12)
x = Add(2)
t = z + x
print(t)
```

И он выдает ошибку TypeError что типа нельзя над двумя разными типами данных `self.argument + other` производить арифметику. Но на счет `return other + self.argument` он чего то молчит.

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться как же все таки работает специальный метод `__add__`. И почему не работает 2 скрипт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый пример можно себе такой цепочкой представить:

```
Add(12) + Add(2)
Add(12).__add__(Add(2))
return Add(2) + 12
Add(2).__add__(12)
return 12 + 2
```

Во втором случае:

```
Add(12) + Add(2)
Add(12).__add__(Add(2))
print(12 + Add(2))
12.__add__(Add(2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Add'
```

Чтобы разрешить `12 + Add(2)`, можно `__radd__` метод определить:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return Add(other + self.argument)
```

`__add__` также может `Add()` возвращать, если не хотите чтобы через пару сложений выражения с `Add()` превращались в обычные `int` объекты. Есть ещё несколько стандартных предположений о числах, к примеру, удобно когда они неизменяемы. Для вдохновления, [можно на `fractions.Fraction` реализацию посмотреть](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2cb4661707818cfd92556e7fdf9068a993577002/Lib/fractions.py#L60).

Comment: Добавлю ещё хорошее описание, как это работает http://www.marinamele.com/2014/04/modifying-add-method-of-python-class.html